# Browser cannot read and send cookies with fetch api even set credentials to include on cross origin request

Tags: reactjs, cookies, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, fetch

Fetching cross origin request, Chrome cannot read `set-cookie` even if I set the `credentials: 'include'` and the server gives:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

[image: chrome]

[image: safari]

It's a react(^16.6.3) project with fetch api

I tried Chrome, Safari, Firefox and mobile browsers, but all these browsers can not read and save cookies. In chrome there's no `Set-Cookie` field, but exist in Safari and Firefox.

[image: empty cookies]

And when I use **postman** to test it, it will be ok, the next request will send the cookies.

```
fetch('http://API_ROOT/api', {
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({})
});
```

Expect the browser to save and send cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many other advices always say: *set credentials: 'includes'* and *server side Access-Control-Allow-Credentials value to true*. But I checked your code and response are both ok.

So maybe the cookie are expired?

Or maybe your browser disabled third party cookies?

[withCredentials MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

> **Third-party cookies**
>
> Note that cookies set in CORS responses are subject to normal third-party cookie policies. In the example above, the page is loaded from foo.example, but the cookie on line 22 is sent by bar.other, and would thus not be saved if the user has configured their browser to reject all third-party cookies.